# Flex 2 columns how to keep the first item's width the same when window is resized

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have two columns and the left column is supposed to have a fixed width while the right column expects to take up the rest of the width. The scenario that I have is when the window is resized, I want to keep the left column's width the same regardless of the length of the text in the right column.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
}

.right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        left aligned column
    </div>    
    <div class="right">
        I want the right column to take up the rest of the space while keeping the left item's width when the window is resized
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        left aligned column
    </div>    
    <div class="right">
        short text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-shrink: 0 or replace width by min-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the property *flex* directly. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) shows that is possible pass up three parameters to flex.

> The flex property may be specified using one, two, or three values.

For more details of use and [flex#syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#syntax)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 400px;
}
.right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left aligned column
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    I want the right column to take up the rest of the space while keeping the left item's width when the window is resized
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left aligned column
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    short text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-grow: 1` its gonna take up the remaining space of the page.
You can read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
}

.right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        left aligned column
    </div>    
    <div class="right">
        I want the right column to take up the rest of the space while keeping the left item's width when the window is resized
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        left aligned column
    </div>    
    <div class="right">
        short text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually want the left columns' width to be the same regardless of the length of the text in the right column. Sorry that the description was not so clear.